# Will IOS private API affect the app publishing on App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, publishing

I have used the `titleForSwipeAccessoryButtonForRowAtIndexPath`,`swipeAccessoryButtonPushedForRowAtIndexPath`(For IOS 7) and `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`(For IOS 8) on my app.

The purpose that I add these two APIs which is for using the swipe to show the delete button which is for delete the items of the row and share button which is for sharing the contents of the row on facebook, whatsapp, twitter etc. And my client need these functions.

The `titleForSwipeAccessoryButtonForRowAtIndexPath` and `swipeAccessoryButtonPushedForRowAtIndexPath` are private APIs. Will my App be rejected by Apple when I publish my App on App Store?

Comment: Please add more information to the question.

Comment: Please tell that for what purpose you are using this private Api's?

Comment: @NirmitDagly The purpose that I add these two APIs which is for using the swipe to show the delete button which is for delete the items of the row and share button which is for sharing the contents of the row on facebook, whatsapp, twitter etc. And my client need these functions.

Comment: are you using UITabelView's row for this?

Comment: @NirmitDagly  Yes and this API work for my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to worry about the app rejection from the apple if you are using this private API's. But make sure that the app doesn't crash while using this API's.
Also, if you are targeting this app for iOS 8.0 or higher, you can achieve this by implementing following method. After this you do not have to worry about any rejection.

```
    -(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
     //do whatever you want to do...
}
```

It is easy to implement and you can add as many buttons as you want to add. Also, implement below delegate method for this code to work.

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Cheers..!!